# Linq query join table

Tags: linq, many-to-many

I have a User table and a group table one user can be part of many groups

```
[USERID]----*-[USERID GROUPID]-*-----[GROUPID]
                (join table)

public partial class user
{
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<group> groups{ get; set; }
}

public partial class group
{
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<user> users{ get; set; }
}
```

1) I need to return all the users that belongs to a specific group

```
var queryable = (from g in db.groups
                  where g.group_id == id
                  select g.users)
                  .ToList()
                  .Select(u => new {    
                      id = u.id,      //Error does not contain definition for id
                      name = u.name   //Error does not contain definition for name
                   });
```

2) I need to return a specific user that belongs to a specific group

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: plants = group sorry I've edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to return all the users that belongs to a specific group

Lambda syntax:

```
db.groups.Where(g => g.group_id == id).SelectMany(g => g.users)
```

Or query syntax:

```
from g in db.groups
where g.group_id == id
from u in g.users
select u
```

> I need to return a specific user that belongs to a specific group

Just like query above, with one additional filter

```
db.groups.Where(g => g.group_id == id)
         .SelectMany(g => g.users)
         .Where(u => u.id == userId)
```

Query syntax:

```
from g in db.groups
where g.group_id == id
from u in g.users
where u.id == userId
select u
```

Comment: I'm starting to undesrtand a little better LINQ Perfect thanks Sergey

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var queryable = (from p in db.plants
             join u in db.users on p.userId equals u.id
              where p.plant_id == plant_id
              select u)
              .ToList()
              .Select(u => new {    
                  id = u.id,      
                  name = u.name   
               });
```

where p.userId is the column which connect plants and users tables

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryable = (from p in db.plants
                join u in db.users on p.userId equals u.id
                where p.plant_id == plant_id
                select new { p.id, p.name, u.name}).ToList();
```

Comment: p doesn't have a user_id property.

Comment: I dun't know about the fields of your db.plants object, it may have some id, please replace it with that id.